# datetime append GMT to the end of the string?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, gmt

I am migrating php code into Python and came across datetime. My code:

```
date_raw = datetime.datetime.strptime(data["Campaign_Start_Date"], '%Y-%m-%d')
date_new = date_raw.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+"T"+"%H:%M:%S GMT")
print(date_new)

# 2020-09-14T00:00:00 GMT
```

My desired output is: `2020-09-14T00:00:00-04:00` So I need to append GMT to the end of the string, but can't find a way to have a proper format back.

Comment: Erm, it seems you just did it…? I mean, you appended `GMT` to the end.

Comment: your desired output seems to have a time zone offset relative to UTC ("-04:00"), however you parse a datetime string with '%Y-%m-%d'. where should the time zone info come from?

Comment: What is the value of `data["Campaign_Start_Date"]` that is being passed to `strptime()`?

Comment: @martineau `2020-09-14`

Comment: @Błotosmętek It has to be this: `2020-09-14T00:00:00-04:00` without `GMT` in the end.

Comment: Can't you just use `date_new = date_raw.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+"T"+"%H:%M:%S-04:00")`?

Comment: @MrFuppes The value of data["Campaign_Start_Date"] is `2020-09-14` I need to somehow convert it so it looks exactly like this: `2020-09-14T00:00:00-04:00` In my understanding -04:00 is Time from GMT.

Comment: @martineau I thought about this option, but I wonder what is the proper way to do this without hardcoding...

Comment: @Chique Please include the input in the question. I'm having a hard time following these comments.

Comment: -04:00 is Time from GMT might correct, but only _your_ local time zone. Do you want to hardcode it?

Comment: So why did you write " I need to append GMT to the end of the string" when in fact you **don't want** to append it?

Comment: @Błotosmętek Whatever this `-04:00` is it needs to be appended to the end of the string. `-04:00` is Time from GMT.

Comment: does your input data hold any info on the timezone in which it was recorded? (note: use timestamps in UTC whenever you can, saves you a lot of work ;-))

Comment: @Chique `-04:00` is a UTC/GMT offset. Eastern Time is currently on UTC-4 under daylight savings, and will be on Sept 14 as well. Based on your profile you're in NJ which is in ET. So do you want to use UTC-4, Eastern Time, or local time?

Comment: @MrFuppes The API returns the date without any info on the timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strptime` doesn't automagically know about the timezone from a time formatted as '%Y-%m-%d', you will have to include that, e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# parse the string
datestring = '2020-05-04'
date = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d')

# add a timezone info
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
date_est = tz.localize(date)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)

print(date_est.isoformat())
# 2020-05-04T00:00:00-04:00
```

Comment: This is still effectively hardcoding the timezone into the code.

Comment: @martineau, sure - you have to define it somewhere I guess. Unless you take e.g. the setting of the machine you run the script on but that sounds pretty unpredictable to me...

Comment: @MrFuppes This works perfectly! Thank you. I accepted the answer.

Comment: @Chique_Code: I'd say if you're sure about the timezone of the input data, you should be fine hardcoding it. However, an API should either strictly use UTC or provide the timezone info (UTC offset at least).